# Detecting BlackBerry and Iphone Browsers in JavaScript or PHP

Tags: php, iphone, browser, blackberry, redirect

i want to **redirect** peaple who goes in my site to other page if they are using a **mobile** browser with a **php** o java script. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very easy will be to parse USER-AGENT string or [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) PHP function. Try :

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
var_dump(get_browser(null, true));
```

Every browser is sending own HTTP_USER_AGENT string.

[Mobile devices USER_AGENT list](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/mobile_ids.html)

For completed solution take a look to [bavotasan](http://bavotasan.com/tutorials/php-code-to-redirect-mobilehandheld-users/) page or just [google](http://www.google.cz/search?q=redirect+mobile+users+php).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to checking the `User-Agent` header, you may also want to check the `X-Wap-Profile` and `Profile` headers, since some third-party browsers may not send a correct `User-Agent` header (they may be spoofing an IE or Firefox header).  The order that I like to check the headers, when looking for mobile clients, is:

1. X-Wap-Profile
2. Profile
3. User-Agent

Answer (score 2):

In javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var deviceAndroid = "android";
        var deviceIphone = "iphone";
        var deviceBlackberry = "blackberry";
        var uagent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        DetectDevice();


        function DetectDevice() {
            if (uagent.search(deviceAndroid) > -1) {}
            else if (uagent.search(deviceIphone) > -1) {}
            else if (uagent.search(deviceBlackberry) > -1) {}
            else { }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the `User-Agent` header:

```
if (preg_match("/(BlackBerry|(iP(hone|od))/i", $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) ) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: there is an error on the code i cant detect, can you please check it?

Answer (score 0):

The $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] contains word "BlackBerry" or "iPhone" respectively. "iPod" too if it's iPod Touch.